# Prove $\left | \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right | \leq\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left | a_k \right |$

Tags: inequality

Prove that if $a_1,...,a_n$ are real numbers then

$\left | \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right | \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left |  a_k \right |$

Where $|x|$ is the absolute of $x$

I dont have any idea, how to solve it. Please help me!

Comment: Can you prove $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$ first?

Comment: After that, use induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$$

Use induction:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k\right| \leq \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right| + |a_{n+1}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} |a_k|$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Prove the desired inequality by induction using the triangle inequality.